# Getting list of current area descriptions from tango api DLL through Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango, google-vr

We are working on a project using tango and VR, and i got to the point of wanting to test to implement it into our app. our app is using both tango and vr in combination, and thus we have both the tango VR sdk and the google VR sdk in out project. We are using the latest verstion of uinty, gvr gvr 1.1 and tango sdk Caporales.

Just for the record we are working in unity and have had a great deal of problems so far, the combination of googlevr and tango sdks seems to do something to each other and cause a lot of issues... We've tried to use different unity versions and different versions of both sdks and found out that a project with both tango and vr sdks can only run if we disable the Tango UX component in the tango manager prefab. I'm not sure what that does exactly but if it is enbaled the app just crashes on launch.

Anyway the problem at hand is that i'm trying to anable the area learning features. I am using the `TangoAreaDescriptionmanager` scene from the example and the code that goes with it. I've isolated the issue to occur in the `AreaDescriptionAPI` class (line 800 or there about in the `AreaDescription` file) in the method called `TangoService_getAreaDescriptionUUIDList`. As soon as that method is called from the `_GetUUIDList` method in the same file the code does not execute furter. mind you that the app does not crash but nothing happens, so there is some error that happens in the external library that i am not albe to figure out.

Does someone have some information on this? 
I'll happlily supply more information if needed.

EDIT: I looked at the logcat from my device and found that the problem maybe is something else... pastebin.com/53Htz9YQ here is the file with relevant logs. It seems to be that the TANGO_CLIENT_API is not being loaded correctly...

Comment: Sorry I can't be more specific, but somewhere I read a bug report or community post talking about a shared library between Google VR and Tango, which had an incompatibility and one would have to exclude the library for them both to play nicely together.  Not sure when the post was from, and can't seem to find it.  Sorry to be not much help!

Comment: I read something like this, which was about the file Plugins/Android/google-unity-wrapper,  and i deleted that one. Is that the one you think of? (link here: https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-cardboard-integration)

Comment: Yes it was ): aah well worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

The application needs to have the `ADF_LOAD_SAVE_PERMISSION` for this call to work. Same thing for the actual loading or saving of a learned area.

Be sure to review this part of the doc: [Tango Permissions and Lifecycle in Unity](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-user-permissions), and especially the "Manually request permissions and connect (Area Learning)" as the workflow is special to handle this permission.

Comment: Do you  mean that i need to add that permission to the android manifest or is it something else? The link you posted doesnt metion anything about that specific permission so is that for somewhere else?

Also the OnTangoPermissions method is called with its permissionGranted parameter as true, so wouldnt that mean all the permissions we granted?

Comment: @blorsten: I work with the Java API so it might use another name or a different way to ask for permissions, but it can't be in the manifest. Do you call the listing of areas within the `OnTangoPermissions` callback? Do you see the dialog asking for the permission?

Comment: Yes, i call for the listing in the OnTangoPermissions method and i see the dialog for the permissions. 

I looked at the logcat from my device and found that the problem maybe is something else... http://pastebin.com/53Htz9YQ here is the file  with relevant logs.
It seems to be that the TANGO_CLIENT_API is not being loaded correctly... Do you know anything about that?